# If I am using just HashMap can I override only hashCode method?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashing, collections

If I need to use only `HashMap`, why do I need to override `equals()` method along with `hashCode()`? How will not implementing `equals()` affect the working of `HashMap`?

Answer (score 7):

The default `equals()` method which your object inherits from class `Object` performs a reference comparison.  This means that no instance of your objects will ever be equal to any other instance, because every individual instance has a different reference.

If no-instance-equal-to-any-other-instance is the behavior you really want, then you don't need to implement `hashCode()` either, because the default `hashCode()` is also based on instance references, so it will also return unique hash-codes.  Besides, in that case, instead of a `HashMap` you can use an `IdentityHashMap` which only looks at references and does not bother with `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

If no-instance-equal-to-any-other-instance is *not* the behavior that you want, then I am afraid you need to also override `equals()` in order to indicate that two objects are non-equal despite having the same hash-code.

If two objects are found to be equal by `equals()` but different by `hashCode()`, this is an error as far as `HashMap` is concerned.  If two objects are found to be unequal by `equals()` but have identical hash-codes, then `HashMap` will consider them as unequal, and it *will* work, *but* it will suffer the (admittedly minor) performance penalty of a hash-code collision.

Comment: tl;dr: For all practical purposes, the answer to "How will not implemeting equals() affect the working of hashmap" is: it will affect the working by it not working at all (as probably intended).

Comment: @JörgWMittag you are right, "for all practical purposes".  I also thought of answering just that at first, (with a bit more explanation as to *why*, of course,) but then I thought of the one exception, which is admittedly unlikely, but possibly enough for some people to downvote, of not wanting any instance to be equal to any other instance.  And I felt that I should mention that for that case, one better *not* override `hashCode()` either.